# scrape the reponse which would be loaded from ajax event

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy tool to scrape content from website, i need help from you guys how to scrape the reponse which is dynamically loaded from ajax.

when content loading from ajax at that mean time url not changing it keep remains same but content would be changed so on that event i need to crawl.

thank you,
G.kavirajan

Comment: have you checked this [link](http://blog.scrapy.org/scraping-ajax-sites-with-scrapy) ??

Comment: Ya i checked the link but i am not able to get the point

Comment: share the website URL so that can help accordingly

Comment: Hi this is url http://addons.prestashop.com/en/ here i need to get the content which would be loading under featured and new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yield FormRequest('http://addons.prestashop.com/en/modules/featureproduct/ajax-homefeatured.php',
        formdata={'type':'new','ajax':'1'},
        callback=self.your_callback_method)
```

Answer (score 0):

bellow are the urls that you can easily catch using [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

this is for featured tab http://addons.prestashop.com/en/modules/featureproduct/ajax-homefeatured.php?ajax=1&type=random

this is for new tab http://addons.prestashop.com/en/modules/featureproduct/ajax-homefeatured.php?ajax=1&type=new

you can request on these url directly to get results you required, although website is using **POST** request to get data for these url, but i tried with parameter **GET** request is also working properly

Comment: Thank you akhter, for your answer when i triying to implement this url in GET i am not getting any response, i dont know how to do it in POST, can u explain how to pass argument (ajax=1& type=new) with start_urls = ['http://addons.prestashop.com/en/modules/featureproduct/ajax-homefeatured.php?']